# How do I handle static file intercept routing in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

**How do I tell Laravel to route `/users/information.php` to `/users/information`?**

So I have a relative link to an existing PHP file. For example:

`/user/information.php`

I am slowly converting my system over to Laravel, but I have to support the existing legacy links. I intend on allowing my 404 handler take care of it in the following way:

1. User navigates to a file that used to exist
   (`/user/information.php`).
2. The system detects the file is no longer there.
3. The 404 handler intercepts the non-existing file and attempts to
   route to the new location (`/user/information`).
4. If the route is found, it routes otherwise throws the 404.

**EDIT:**

I am hoping there is way to write something without doing a redirect like:

```
$router->get('/user/information.php', UserController::class . '@information');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the method that ended up being the solution I used:

```php
Route::get('user/information{extension?}', ['uses'  => UserController::class . '@information'])
    ->where(['extension' => '\..+']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think you can catch the `NotFoundHttpException`. Put this code at `render` method in file `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```php
if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {

    $path = \Request::getPathInfo();

    if (\File::exists($path)) {

        // If "/user/information.php" was found, show it.

    } else {

        // Remove the ".php" suffix
        $path = str_replace('.php', '', $path);

        $routeCollection = \Route::getRoutes();
        $routes = $routeCollection->getRoutes();

        // Find the match route
        foreach($routes as $route) 
        {
            // Detect if "/user/information" route exists
            if ($route->getUri() == $path) 
            {
                // Redirect to match route
                return redirect()->to($path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I should have been more clear. Is there a way to do it without a redirect? I used "intercept" I should have more clearly stated it that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('user/information.php', function () {
    return redirect('user/information');
});
```

I think you should be able to set up the redirect in your routes file. Does this work?

Comment: Can you forward a POST?

Comment: Why would you need to redirect a POST, you shouldn't get through such a situation. POST comes from within your application they should not be bookmarked links?

Comment: You are correct. However, do to the nature of legacy code, there could be other locations that have a form that posts to the same link. So I want to avoid the potential of that breaking too. I know it's crazy! But on the up side, our legacy code IS getting cleaned up. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered how I could intercept the route without doing a redirect.

```php
// Handle a legacy route from a .php file
if (preg_match('/\.php/', Request::getRequestUri())) {
    $legacyPath = ltrim(str_replace('.php', '', Request::getRequestUri()), '/');
    $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
    $actionMethod = Request::getMethod();
    foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
        // if the path exists for the given method, call it!
        if ($value->getPath() == $legacyPath && in_array($actionMethod, $value->getMethods())) {
            $method = strtolower($actionMethod);
            // the empty override method that allows the method to be called without redirecting
            Route::$method('', $value->getAction()['controller']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not redirect? Do you plan to permanently support both sets of URLs?

Comment: I do not plan on permanently but at the same time the redirect is indefinite. Also, I don't want to have to handle all of the nuances with POST, GET, PUT, and DELETE parameters that may get passed with the request.